# Why did he turn on the TV vs why the man turned on the TV

Tags: word-choice, questions, past-simple

> Why did the man turn on the TV ?
>
> Why the man turned on the TV ?

Sometimes, I guess, I hear or see these two constructions, so what is the difference ? Does the second is more often in sopken language ? And do both of them are formal ?

Thank you

Comment: The second is ungrammatical and both are badly punctuated.

Comment: As for the second sentence, do you think it maybe used in spoken language ?

Comment: In some kind of patois, perhaps, but definitely not in normal conversation.

Comment: "Why the man turned on the TV ?" would only be spoken by someone who does not have English as a first language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why did the man turn on the TV?

Why the man turned on the TV.

The first sentence is a direct question.  It's complete and correct grammatically.

The second sentence is part of an indirect question.   As a complete indirect question, you can, for example, say:

I wonder why the man turned on the TV.

Could you tell me why the man turned the TV on?

I want to know why the man turned on the TV.

Answer (score 2):

When asking questions with interrogatory words (Who, What, When, Where, Why, How), we use a helper verb with the bare infinitive. The plain tensed verb is not used.

> Why **did** he **turn** on the TV?
>
> Why he turned on the TV? <sup>ungrammatical</sup>
>
> Why **do** you **go** into the city?
>
> Why you go into the city? <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

We can also use the participle:

> Why **was** the man **turning** on the TV?
>
> Why **are** you **going** into the city?

P.S. Hundreds of years ago, the situation was different, and an English speaker could ask a question without a helper verb and using a different word order:

Why **go** you into the city? <sup>archaic</sup>

What **said** he about their misfortune? <sup>archaic</sup>

Comment: BUT: I ask why you go into the city. He is asking why he turned on the TV. These are OK in indirect speech.

Comment: @Lambie: Yes, but the original question is about asking a question, not about making a statement about a question.